# C Makefile Issue

Tags: c, makefile

I'm fairly new to C. I made a program that I wanted to run as Lex, which requires 3 .c files, getLine.c (header file: getLine.h), mainLex.c (the main function), and Lex1.c.

Lex1.c and mainLex.c both have header files history.h, lex.h, and getLine.h.

So, I tried to produce a makefile that connects all of these. Here's what I can up with:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g3 -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall
HWK = /c/cs323/Hwk4/
objects = getLine.o mainLex.o Lex1.o

Lex : $(objects)
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o Lex $(objects)

getLine.o: ${HWK}getLine.c 
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c ${HWK}getLine.c

Lex1.o: Lex1.c ${HWK}history.h ${HWK}lex.h
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c Lex1.c

mainLex.o: Lex1.c ${HWK}history.h ${HWK}lex.h
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c Lex1.c
```

This actually makes, but I'm getting very strange errors in the code. For instance, I declare a data structure

```
token
```

in lex.h, but I get the errors

```
error: unknown type name ‘token’
     token *cmmd;                   //   String containing token 

error: unknown type name ‘token’
 void hRemember (int ncmd, token *list)
```

It's as if the makefile isn't taking into account the header files. What is wrong?

Comment: I think the problem lies in not including the header files in the c code

Comment: Another issue could be that you declare a `struct token`, but don't use a `typedef` to define a new type. If you just declare a struct, you must use the `struct` keyword, e.g. `struct token *cmmd`. It's hard to tell without knowing the contents of `lex.h`, though.

Comment: This doesn't look like a makefile problem.